# Why does pytorch lightnings configure_optimizer throw AssertionError: param group must be a dict?

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I have set up multiple pytorch lightning projects in the past and while setting up a new quick demo project, I stumbled across this weird error and somehow I cannot get rid of it.

Here are the relevant sections of my model file..

```
class TSModel(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.backbone = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(3, 10, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding=(1, 1)),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(2, 2), stride=(2, 2))
        )

        self.classifier = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(10*16*16, 128),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(128, 10)
        )

        self.criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

    def forward(self, x):
        N = x.shape[0]
        x = self.backbone(x)
        x = x.view(N, -1)
        return self.classifier(x)

    def configure_optimizers(self):
        params = [p for p in self.parameters() if p.requires_grad]
        return torch.optim.AdamW(self.parameters())
```

However, when starting the training process, the program exits and the following is thrown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/torchserve-example/main.py", line 25, in <module>
    ts_train()
  File "/torchserve-example/main.py", line 21, in ts_train
    trainer.fit(model, datamodule)
  File ".local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py", line 458, in fit
    self._run(model)
  File ".local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py", line 715, in _run
    self.accelerator.setup(self, model)  # note: this sets up self.lightning_module
  File ".local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/accelerators/cpu.py", line 39, in setup
    return super().setup(trainer, model)
  File ".local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/accelerators/accelerator.py", line 92, in setup
    self.setup_optimizers(trainer)
  File ".local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/accelerators/accelerator.py", line 374, in setup_optimizers
    optimizers, lr_schedulers, optimizer_frequencies = self.training_type_plugin.init_optimizers(
  File ".local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/plugins/training_type/training_type_plugin.py", line 190, in init_optimizers
    return trainer.init_optimizers(model)
  File ".local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/optimizers.py", line 34, in init_optimizers
    optim_conf = model.configure_optimizers()
  File "/torchserve-example/model.py", line 52, in configure_optimizers
    return torch.optim.AdamW(self.parameters())
  File ".local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/optim/adamw.py", line 47, in __init__
    super(AdamW, self).__init__(params, defaults)
  File ".local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/optim/optimizer.py", line 55, in __init__
    self.add_param_group(param_group)
  File ".local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/optim/optimizer.py", line 242, in add_param_group
    assert isinstance(param_group, dict), "param group must be a dict"
AssertionError: param group must be a dict
```

When I execute `print(type(params[0]))` in the `configure_optimizers`, it prints `<class 'torch.nn.parameter.Parameter'>` to `stdout`. Any idea what went wrong here?

**Note:** As this error occurs during initialization of the optimizer, this is probably not directly related to pytorch lightning which is why I included pytorch as a tag as well.

Answer (score 0):

In the library code, I found:

```
# if not isinstance(param_groups[0], dict):
#             param_groups = [{'params': param_groups}]
```

When commenting this in, everything works normally.
I leave the question open because it does not feel like a good solution to change the underlying library or to just copy this code section to my file.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this line is wrong in your code:

```
def configure_optimizers(self):
        params = [p for p in self.parameters() if p.requires_grad]
        return torch.optim.AdamW(self.parameters())
```

You are passing `params` not `self.parameters()` as that would work fine.

With `params` created like this you are essentially passing list with generator inside, **which is not an instance of dict**.

In PyTorch it is possible to pass multiple different parameters with different learning rates etc. via dicts contained in lists. This is what your params looks like to PyTorch’s API.